# Parse and Display Laravel updated_at timestamp using moment.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, momentjs, laravel-7

I have a Laravel object created and contains

```
attributes: array:8 [▼
    "id" => 252
    "babyId" => "1"
    "type" => "pee"
    "method" => "POST"
    "logId" => "3287"
    "note" => "{"id":3287,"type":"pee","created_at":"2021-04-12T10:08:21.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-04-12T10:08:21.000000Z","note":"","babyId":"1"}"
    "created_at" => "2021-04-12 06:08:21"
    "updated_at" => "2021-04-12 06:08:21"
]
```

If you notice these 2 columns

```
> "note" => "{"id":3287,"type":"pee","created_at":"2021-04-12T10:08:21.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-04-12T10:08:21.000000Z","note":"","babyId":"1"}"



> "updated_at" => "2021-04-12 06:08:21"
```

I've tried to parse my note column

```
var note = JSON.parse($(this).find('td:last-child').text());
var updated_at = moment(note.updated_at).format('hh:mm a');
```

As you can see the result show 4 mins diff. What did I do wrong?

[image]

If I clicked on note, modal trigger

[image]

Did I do something on moment.js ?

---

**codes**

```
<body>

    <div class="container ">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-sm-12">

                <table class="table fixed_header">
                    <thead class="thin-border-bottom">
                        <th width="5%">ID</th>
                        <th width="10%">logId</th>
                        <th width="10%">Method</th>
                        <th width="5%">Type</th>
                        <th width="20%">At</th>
                        <th width="20%">Ago</th>
                        <th width="30%">Note</th>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody class="tbody-log">

                        @foreach ($babyLogAudits as $log)

                        <tr data-type="{{ $log->type }}" id="tr-{{$log->id}}" class="text-{{$log->type}}">
                            <td>{{$log->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$log->logId}}</td>
                            <td><span class="badge-{{$log->method}}">{{$log->method}}</span></td>
                            <td >
                                <a class="btn btn-{{ $log->type }}" >
                                    <img class="logIconSmall" src="/assets/be/img/baby/{{$log->type}}.png?q={{microtime()}}" />
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ date('H:m a', strtotime($log->created_at)) }}</td>
                            <td>{{ DateHelper::ago($log->created_at) }} ago.</td>


                            <td id="note-{{$log->id}}"><code>{{$log->note}}</code></td>
                        </tr>

                        @endforeach

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                if ($(window).width() < 600) {

                    $('td:nth-child(2)').hide();
                    $('td:nth-child(5)').hide();
                    $('td:nth-child(7)').hide();


                    $('th:nth-child(2)').hide();
                    $('th:nth-child(5)').hide();
                    $('th:nth-child(7)').hide();

                }


                $("tr").click(function() {

                    var note = JSON.parse($(this).find('td:last-child').text());

                    var created_at = moment(note.created_at).format('hh:mm a');
                    var updated_at = moment(note.updated_at).format('hh:mm a');


                    if(updated_at == created_at){
                        var displayText = updated_at;
                    } else {
                        var displayText = created_at + ' ' + updated_at;
                    }


            // moment(updatedAt).format('hh:mm a');

            console.log(created_at, updated_at);



            var popupTemplate = `
            <div class="modal fade" style="background-color:black, color:white; ">
            <div class="model-content" style="margin-top: 200px;">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">updated_at : ${displayText}
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            `;

            $(popupTemplate).modal();

        });


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Highly unlikely that this is due to date conversion/formatting. Since the previous item has the same time (6:04 am), I'd check if the code in charge of displaying these values didn't accidentally copy that one.

Comment: Also, quick tip, if you are working with laravel, avoid doing `date('H:m a', strtotime($log->created_at))`, use `Carbon` like `$log->created_at->format('H:m a')` and done, same for `DateHelper::ago`, if you want to get `8 seconds ago` or `10 minutes ago` or similar, you can do `$log->created_at->diffForHumans()`... More info [here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference).